# nodejs websocket test returning error about encoding

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am trying out my hand at nodejs and websockets.  I have some simple server logic that listens on port 8000.  when a request comes in i try to create a websocket.

Then I have a client ... that listens on port 8000 via ws protocol.

**What's Working**

when i launch the server page... myservername.com:8000 it correctly shows the "I am connected"

**What's Not Working**

When I try to run the client side (html file), nothing seems to work. 
I try to launch like this:  myservername.com:8000/justWs.html, I see the following behavior:

- it shows the "I am connected message" on the page.
- i see the following error message in the console in f12:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol.

**Server Code:**

this is what my justWsServer.js file looks like:

```
const http = require('http');
//3rd party module, ws
const websocket = require('ws');

//create basic http server
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  //res.header("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    res.end("I am connected")
});

/*
creating a new websocket server on line 15. NB: per the docs at https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#class-websocketserver, 
you need to pass it a "pre-created Node.js HTTP/S server.   we created that server on line 6
*/

const wss = new websocket.Server({server});
//headers event.

wss.on('headers', (headers, req)=>{
  //res.header("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
  console.log(headers);
});
server.listen(8000); // if http traffic shows up on port 8000, we create a server with a request, and a result.
```

**justWs.html**

This is what the client side looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
   </head>
<script>
    let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');  //nb no http protocol but web socket protocol.
    console.log(ws);
</script>
</html>
```

As you can see on the server side, I was playing around with encoding types.  But I haven't been able to resolve my issue.

**Folder Structure**

```
root@server:/var/www/socketiotest# ls -lah
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jun 13 16:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Jun 13 15:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  194 Jun 17 10:06 justWs.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  802 Jun 17 09:27 justWsServer.js
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Jun 13 15:59 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  672 Jun 13 15:59 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  253 Jun 13 15:59 package.json
```

Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I think I found part of the problem.  As you saw from my post, both the "client" (html file) and the server (justWsServer.js) file were living on my web host's VM.
I was trying to trigger the creation of a web socket between the two by launching the html like so:

http://myserver.com:8000/justWs.html

I copied the HTML file over to my local laptop where I'm programming. Changed

```
 ws://localhost:8000
```

to

```
 ws://myserver.com:8000
```

And then I just opened it up in chrome.  now the code is working and I can see it creating a web socket.  No more errors either about encoding.
I would still like to know how to run both client and server from my webhost.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` inside header tag and it will work.

Comment: I replaced the existing meta tag with the one you suggested and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I followed exact same steps and used your content to replicate the scenario, However, I could not able to reproduce it. I am using Chrome (Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)) to validate. Even, I could able to see ```ws``` log into inspect console.